# What is another phrase for the cliche "twists and turns"?

Tags: phrase-requests, cliche

I am writing a creative writing piece in which I have used the cliche "twists and turns". I need another phrase that I could use so that it does not sound boring. The sentence is,

> 'The bluff rises above the river that twists and turns beneath, trying to find a way out of the maze of mountains.'

Comment: You could use 'snakes' or 'wanders' or 'wanders back and forth' or, less ideally, 'weaves'.

Comment: Why do you need another phrase, when you have to use the cliché? Also, why do they make you use a cliché?

Comment: [**meander**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/meandering) *verb **"flow in a winding course" (of rivers),** 1610s, from **meander** (noun). Of a person, "to wander aimlessly"*. It's also used of ***roads*** and other things, but idiomatically it's very closely associated with ***rivers*** in particular.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on writers.SE, as it is asking for help with writing.

Comment: "... the river that flows [***sinuously***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sinuous) beneath..."

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is **Winding** - [**M-W**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/winding)

> having a course made up of a series of twists and turns.

**Wind**

> move in or take a twisting or spiral course.

**Example**: The path wound among olive trees.

Your sentence can be modified as,

> 'The bluff rises above the river that *winds* beneath, trying to find a way out of the maze of mountains.'

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps *writhe*. Although it usually refers to movements of the body, there are other uses, e.g., knot theory, where it refers to twisting; http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/writhe

*... above the river that writhes below looking for ...* sounds good.

Comment: Snakes writhe.  Rivers don't writhe.

Comment: @aparente001 It is a figure of speech. Rivers *twist*, and they also *writhe*.

Comment: You are misusing "nonsense" too.  The tone of that word is not what is expected on this site.  It is fine to disagree here, but we are supposed to be more respectful than that.